# Can anyone think of any astronomical phenomenon that could be due to engineering projects of an advanced civilzation?

Tags: astrophysics

It has always seemed to me that there could very well be evidence of advanced civilizations in other parts of the galaxy/universe that are staring us in the face.  Within a thousand years, heck, maybe a hundred, it seems likely that we would have engineering projects so vast that you could see them across the galaxy, once the light/energy output/whatever reached that far.  So, I was wondering if there were any structures/phenomena that come to mind for anyone.  I've run across a few that intrigue me but I can't say I really have the background to say anything that would be valid.  Also, I'm kinda surprised that this isn't one of the tools identified explicitly in SETI.  Maybe it's implied.

Comment: This appears to be off topic

Comment: There's also the [WOW! signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal).  If you look at the [Fermi paradox](http://waitbutwhy.com/2014/05/fermi-paradox.html), there are a number of deep thoughts about this issue, for example, civilisations may be trying to keep a low profile against predator civilisation (which is why SETI listens, rather than broadcasts!)

Comment: Ummm, Sean, off the topic of astrophysics?

Comment: Dr. Xorile, Thanks for the Wow! signal, I had never heard of it before  But, that seems like what we typically look for, right?  Some signal sent out as if it was intended as a signal.  The Dyson sphere is more like that which I'm thinking but, even that is wide of the mark.

Comment: I take it back (sorry, can't figure out why some posts won't let me edit), that would probably fall exactly into the category of what I was thinking, though I envisioned more of a sustained, observable phenomenon rather than a signal.

Answer (score 3):

There has been a number of search for possibly engineering projects in space. The one I remember the most is a paper running a search for Dyson spheres from astronomical data, some of the results are listed here :

http://home.fnal.gov/~carrigan/infrared_astronomy/Fermilab_search.htm

Comment: Dyson spheres is interesting to me in that I was thinking of structures discovered, not envisioned.  Interesting.  As a simple example of what I was thinking, Gamma ray bursts.  I think that GRBs are mostly understood and not too mysterious but, it is something that could be set off by an intentional engineering project of an advanced civilization.  Or, that humongous structure of galaxies that takes up 1/9th of the known universe.  Or, magnestars.  I don't forward these as serious examples because I don't think I'm qualified to make any serious suggestions.